# JSF 2.2 @RequestScope

Tags: jsf-2.2

I have a big doubt about @RequestScope bean.
I have a data table populated by an array list like this:

```
if(eventiCentroUtente == null){

    eventiCentroUtente = eventoMgmtService.getEventiByCentroCinofiloId(getCurrentBeanUtente().getUtenteCorrente().getCentroCinofilo().getIdCentro());

}
```

As you can see array list population depends on enduser param (getCurrentBeanUtente().getUtenteCorrente().getCentroCinofilo().getIdCentro())!
So....if I login two different users I will see the same array list because only for the first time the list is null! The second array list is not null and populated by first user request param!
Why?
I would a new bean for a new request and so on I would a new array list!

What I did not understand?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions!
Have a nice day!

Vale

Comment: Which JSF implementation are you using?

Comment: I'm using javax.faces-2.2.jar and primefaces-3.5.jar.

Comment: You're not showing enough code, or giving enough background on your code.

Comment: I need to inject spring services into my BB and I've configured it with this annotations:

Component
ManagedBean(name="visualizzazioneCentroCinofilo")
RequestScoped

If I add Scope("request") annotation my BB works fine and I can see a new bean and a new list for a new request!